# location module have problem with field collection it's not appearing in view

Tags: 7, views, entities, location

I have used [location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) module inside field collection.
If we use location as a normal field (Outside the field collection) then it will appear in both view and node details but if we use inside the field collection it will not show country or city in view please see the below screen shorts.

[image]
Details field is location module which is used in field collection module.

Country and all necessary information is appearing in node details as you can see the above screen short which is highlighted on red color.

[image]
But while using in view it will not show the country I have tried both field which is appearing in above screen short

Country= Field collection item: country
Countrylocationonly= location: coutry